# How can I clear core0 of any interrupts?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, cpu, interrupts, affinity

So by default windows is using core 0 for most driver work, for some reason it prefers that core over the others.
With interrupt affinty policy tool, I can move some of the devices using core0 for interrupts to different cores, but not everything.

My question is, is there a way I can make the OS(w10) prefer to put stuff on core 1 instead of 0 by default? Or is there another way to get core 0 interrupt free?

You might ask why I want to do this. Reason is I'm bored and doing a little experiment...but a solution would be greatly appreciated nonetheless!
Have a nice day!

Comment: While an interesting experiment, if it is hardwired or certain early starting processes are otherwise reliant on things being delivered to core 0 it may be that the *easiest* way to move things would be to get a job at Microsoft as a kernel developer and do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows feature, and it seems that your core 0 is fractionally faster
than your core 1, or that it better supports Intel Turbo Boost Technology.

In the Microsoft blog article
[Testing the throttled delivery approach for 19H2](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2019/08/26/testing-the-throttled-delivery-approach-for-19h2/)
you can find this text:

> A CPU may have multiple “favored” cores (logical processors of the highest available scheduling class). To provide better performance and reliability, we have implemented a rotation policy that distributes work more fairly among these favored cores.

Your core 0 is probably defined by Windows as a "favored core", but not your core 1.

The technology related to "favored cores" seems to be
[Intel Turbo Boost Technology](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html).
You may be able to disable it in the BIOS, but you will lose the ability
of one of your cores (probably core 0) to boost up to a higher frequency
under heavy load.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! 
Turboboost is already disabled in my bios, but core 0 is favored(I think it has to do with proximity to other hardware).
I wonder if this "rotation policy" can be altered in some way.....

Comment: I don't think so, this is an internal Windows algorithm.